# nginx - php-fpm: access restrictions for some php pages

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I have a folder containing some PHP files served with php-fpm (fastcgi); inside tihs folder, I have a file which I want to be allowed for internal IPs and deny for external.

The problem I have is that with this configuration...

```
# PHP
location ~ ^\/some\/path\/(.*\.php)$ {
  alias /some/path/;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  # # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  #
  # # With php5-cgi alone:
  # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  # # With php5-fpm:
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  # Changes due to the alias declaration
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /$1;
}

# PHP: phpinfo() access restrictions
location = /some/path/phpinfo.php {
  allow 10.0.0.0/24;
  deny all;
}
```

...access to `/some/path/phpinfo.php` is managed correctly but the fastcgi rules are not applied (I download the `phpinfo.php` file); while with this configuration...

```
# PHP
location ~ ^\/some\/path\/(.*\.php)$ {
  alias /some/path/;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  # # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
  #
  # # With php5-cgi alone:
  # fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  # # With php5-fpm:
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  # Changes due to the alias declaration
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$1;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /$1;
}

# PHP: phpinfo() access restrictions
location ~ ^\/some\/path\/phpinfo\.php$ {
  allow 10.0.0.0/24;
  deny all;
}
```

...`/some/path/phpinfo.php` is interpreted correctly but access restrictions are not applied.

How can I fix the configuration in order that `/some/path/phpinfo.php` gets interpreted and access restrictions are applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx only applies *one* location block at the same level, so it's either going to apply the first one (with the FastCGI but no access control) *or* the second one (with access control by no FastCGI). To have them both applied you need to nest them like so:

```
location ~ ^\/some\/path\/(.*\.php)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

    location /some/path/phpinfo.php {
        allow 10.0.0.0/24;
        deny all;
    }
}
```